# DDD directory structure for MVC app

Tags: mvc, domain-driven-design, laravel

As a means of learning and gaining some experience with domain-driven design, I'm restructuring/refactoring an old application written in PHP which utilizes the Laravel 5.1 framework.  Below is a mock-up of a simplified structure I came up with to begin my refactoring process which includes, in part, the default Laravel 5.1 'app' directory structure ([found here](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/tree/5.1/app)). **For clarity, the following statements may help clarify the provided structure:**

- User represents an Aggregate Root.
- The domain directory underneath aggregate roots will contain any
  entities, events, exceptions and DAO/Repository interfaces.
- Although User does is not complex enough to subdivide its
  directories, certain AR's will be further broken down by aggregates
  in their respective Application, Domain, and Infrastructure
  directories.

**Things I've specifically debated are:**

- Where to place event listeners, (*currently in Application directories*).
- Where to place shared functionality, (*currently in Core directory*).
- Whether or not to include the Http and Console/Cli directories
  underneath each aggregate root directory, (*currently keeping everything framework-specific in its default location*).
- Whether to place Application/Domain/Infrastructure directories as
  top-level directories under ProjectName dir or (as I have done),
  place them underneath top-level AR directories.

Any tips and/or advice on best practices in DDD application structure is greatly appreciated.

```
app/
    Console/
    Exceptions/
    Http/
    Policies/
        UserPolicy.php
    ProjectName/
        Core/
            Application/
            Domain/
            Infrastructure/
        User/
            Application/
                Listeners/
                    LogUserWasCreated.php
                    LogUserWasUpdated.php
                Presenters/
                    UserProfilePresenter.php
                Services/
                    CreateUserService.php
                    FindUserService.php
                    UpdateUserService.php
            Domain/
                Role.php
                RoleDAO.php
                User.php
                UserDAO.php
                UserNotCreated.php
                UserNotFound.php
                UserNotUpdated.php
                UserWasCreated.php
                UserWasUpdated.php
            Infrastructure/
                EloquentRoleDAO.php
                EloquentUserDAO.php
    Providers/
        UserServiceProvider.php
```